# Файл/контролер который отвечает за отправку транзакционых писем в magento?

Tags: magento

Здравствуйте нужно поменять шаблон письма отправляемого клиенту после заказа. В админ панели менял, но я так понимаю, программист который делал сайт сменил настройке в коде, ибо смена любого транзакционого письма не чего не дает. Кто может подсказать где находится файл/контролер который отвечает за отправку транзакционых писем в magento?

Comment: Magento 1 или 2?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau Magento 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно отловить темплейт письма, то посмотрите метод `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::sendTransactional()` (`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php`)

Обратите внимание на следующий код:

```
if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
    $queue = $this->getQueue();
    $this->load($templateId);
    $this->setQueue($queue);
} else {
    $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
    $this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
}
```

Не забудьте заранее поискать нет переписывает ли другой модуль эту модель, т.к. это наиболее частая проблема с отправкой писем.